# Why is my login not permitting data GET through the API in my React ASP.NET Core Application?

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, adal

I am working on an ASP.NET Core React with Redux application which lives in an Azure `webapp`.  I recently wanted to integrate Azure Active Directory or AAD into my application to utilise the single sign-on login for my users.

To achieve this, I opted to use the [react-adal from github](https://github.com/salvoravida/react-adal).  The integration of which is very lightweight and seems to work well.

Since adding `react-adal` I have found that my application fails to fetch data through any of my API's even after I have logged in.  Looking at the network calls in the console I can see a `302` status reported back from any GET request that is sent to the API.

Looking at the information provided, I can see a response header of

```
Location https://login.microsoftonline...
```

So I can see that when it's requesting data, it's still attempting to authenticate even though I've already logged in.  I have passed my API via Postman and, as expected, it asks me to log in, so I know that it's an authentication issue.

My question is, why, after I log in, does it still not register that I'm authenticated or have I done something wrong with my integration of `react-adal`?

Here is my setup of both my react-adal and also my azure active directory application.

**ClientApp/src/adalConfig**

```
import { AuthenticationContext, adalFetch, withAdalLogin } from 'react-adal';

export const adalConfig = {
    tenant: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    endpoints: {
        api: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    },
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
};

export const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);

export const adalApiFetch = (fetch, url, options) =>
    adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api, fetch, url, options);

export const withAdalLoginApi = withAdalLogin(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api);
```

**ClientApp/src/index.js**

```
import { runWithAdal } from 'react-adal';
import { authContext } from './adalConfig';

const DO_NOT_LOGIN = false;

runWithAdal(authContext, () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    require('./indexApp.js')
}, DO_NOT_LOGIN)
```

**ClientApp/src/indexApp.js**

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "./assets/css/site.css";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { ConnectedRouter } from "react-router-redux";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import configureStore from "./store/configureStore";
import App from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";

// Create browser history to use in the Redux store
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].getAttribute("href");
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: baseUrl });

// Get the application-wide store instance, prepopulating with state from the server where available.
const initialState = window.initialReduxState;
const store = configureStore(history, initialState);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    rootElement
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

**ClientApp/appsettings.json**

```
"AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Domain": "mycompany.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "AppIDURL": "https://mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/myappname",
    "ConfigView": "MVC"
  }
```

**Azure/App Registration/Manifest**

```
{
  "appId": "6239a5f3-bf08-4935-9140-2ed0a8f2dad9",
  "appRoles": [],
  "availableToOtherTenants": false,
  "displayName": "Hagland Broker",
  "errorUrl": null,
  "groupMembershipClaims": null,
  "optionalClaims": null,
  "acceptMappedClaims": null,
  "homepage": "https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/",
  "informationalUrls": {
    "privacy": null,
    "termsOfService": null
  },
  "identifierUris": [
    "https://mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/MyApplication"
  ],
  "keyCredentials": [],
  "knownClientApplications": [],
  "logoutUrl": null,
  "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
  "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
  "oauth2Permissions": [
    {
      "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access MyApplication on behalf of the signed-in user.",
      "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access MyApplication",
      "id": "xxx",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "type": "User",
      "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access MyApplication on your behalf.",
      "userConsentDisplayName": "Access MyApplication",
      "value": "user_impersonation"
    }
  ],
  "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
  "objectId": "xxxx",
  "parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
  },
  "passwordCredentials": [
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": null,
      "endDate": "2020-04-23T14:50:19.7214445Z",
      "keyId": "xxx",
      "startDate": "2019-04-23T14:50:19.7544684Z",
      "value": null
    }
  ],
  "publicClient": false,
  "replyUrls": [
    "https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/"
  ],
  "requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
      "resourceAppId": "xxxx",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "xxxx",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "xxxx",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "samlMetadataUrl": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ADAL js uses a hidden Iframe to make the token request to Azure AD. It is designed to return an ID token when the resource for which the token is being requested is the same as the client application. When an ID token is returned, it cached by the library. So when we use **authenticationContext.acquireToken(resource, callback)**, it allows the application to obtain tokens silently without prompting the user again.

In your case, code seems fine, could you check the adalConfig.endpoints.api value, it should match with the AppID uri of service principal, according to the above manifest file the adalConfig.endpoints.api value should be "https://mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/MyApplication".